# NVIDIA video driver issue (error code 43) introduced by Windows 10 Fall Creator's Update

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce, display-driver

I have faced this issue for a few weeks now and it has disabled my multi-monitor setup and greatly decreased my productivity. I seek a workaround or resolution from someone who's already dealt with it. The trouble is happening on my Acer Aspire AX3400G-U4802 desktop PC. I've posted the issue at the [Acer](https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/536929/acer-aspire-ax3400g-u4802-desktop-pc-nvidia-geforce-9200-drivers-for-windows-10#latest) website, [NVIDIA](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/account/questions/detail/i_id/1375590), and [Microsoft](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/is-there-a-fix-for-error-code-43-on-my-nvidia/b68ba349-9c22-49ae-ba4d-f59bc2c3e2b5).

So far, not one of these companies has given me an adequate answer though I hear the problem has affected many PC users that depend on NVIDIA graphics. I'd appreciate hearing from anyone that has gotten any further than I have!

My Windows 10 Pro installation was automatically upgraded to Windows 10 Pro version 1709 recently and it's since then that my NVIDIA GeForce 9200 on-board graphics card fails with the message

```
Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)
```

I have tried various versions of the NVIDIA driver, even using [3DGuru's DDU (Display Driver Uninstaller)](http://www.guru3d.com/files-tags/download-ddu.html) to completely remove the new driver and start over but it's been no use.

I do have a dual-boot setup, so going back to Windows 7 does show me that all my hardware is fine. Also, prior to this upgrade to Windows 10 version 1709, whatever version of Windows 10 I had earlier was running just fine.

I've even restored my old Windows 10 version using the built-in Windows 10 Restore procedure and everything worked again. I noticed that the working NVIDIA driver was v341.81 at this point.

Eventually, however, Win10 still goes back and upgrades that driver up to v342.01 against my wishes and destroys my multi-monitor setup again. While that error code 43 appears in Device Manager, my Windows 10 environment won't detect my second monitor and displays graphics very slowly.

Attempting to force Windows not to install further driver updates doesn't seem to help; it still goes out and updates my video card driver.

Does anyone know of a sure-fire correction to this issue?

Comment: Have you seen any of the solutions here: https://superuser.com/questions/1156317/nvidia-graphics-card-no-longer-works-in-windows-10-error-code-43-but-works-in?rq=1

Comment: Which leads you to this question: https://superuser.com/questions/964475/how-do-i-stop-windows-10-from-updating-my-graphics-driver/968749#968749 once you have a "good" driver you can block Windows from updating it.

Comment: Your latter method to block driver updates on a specific driver is new to me; the method I tried used the Group Policy Editor per http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-disable-windows-update-in-windows-10/) as well but didn't seem to effectively curb the updates. I will try your way per that last link you posted and report back.

Comment: Alright here I am after following the steps but I'm finding myself in the same predicament--however, I've also determined something else has changed: although my NVIDIA GeForce 9200 version is back to 341.81, Windows 10 is currently at version 10.0.16299 Build 16299. When that NVIDIA driver version was last found working on my machine, the Windows version I had was also 10.0.10240 Build 10240.

Comment: Therefore, it seems I have not just a driver issue but also some sort of incompatibility with even this pre-FCU (Fall Creator's Update) version of Windows! I'll have to do a complete Windows Recovery again if I hope to get any closer to my working environment, and hopefully then I'll also be able to run this Microsoft utility mentioned in your link (wushowhide.diagcab) in time to stop the automatic update of the driver, as well as perform the other steps in the other Group Policy Editor link I mentioned above to hopefully ALSO stop Windows 10 from upgrading at all. What do you think?

Comment: I went to look and see if I could restore the previous version of Windows that I knew worked in combination with the previous NVIDIA driver but it seems I lost the ability to return to the previous version of Windows. At one point after the FCU release the option was available to me, but now it's not. I have Restore Points available, but I don't think any of them go as far back as I need. I feel stumped. I guess I could wipe everything and start over from scratch and try to avoid these pitfalls in the future, but boy what a burden that would be.

Comment: I do remember hearing about one of the updates to Win10 forcing an update to the wddm system which would have meant display driver updates and broken old drivers.  10240 was literally the initial release of Win10. If that was what you were running then you missed *all* of the other major updates. At this point i would bite the bullet and just buy a new graphics card, the 9200 is ancient and anything vaguely recent is going to be better.

Comment: UPDATE: Something curious happened the other day: an image of the mouse with the little progress circle next to it remained stuck on one of my extended screens as I was moving it around during boot time. The actual mouse was still operational on the main screen. It seems that the video for that particular screen had somehow fallen into a hung state. That particular video screen is displayed by a j5create JUA370 USB to VGA adapter. I'm investigating this right now with the j5create folks at https://j5createticket.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/requests/54244.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has cleared up now. If you read my latest UPDATE on the comments to the original question, I got a hunch that my additional video screens driven off j5create JUA370 USB to VGA adapters were somehow conflicting with the NVIDIA driver. What I did then was download the latest driver (j5create-USB_Multi_Adapter-18.01.0118.3192.exe) for the JUA370 unit at https://en.j5create.com/collections/display-adapters/products/jua370?variant=10609924868. I executed the setup file I had downloaded there, rebooted, and that was it! So it seems that either the FCU installation disabled the original driver, or it removed the driver completely, or the J5 guys released a new version of the driver that wasn't automatically updated when the FCU update took place on my PC and I was left with having to manually investigate what the issue was and install the latest driver myself.