# What can I do to fix "Code 43" AMD graphics driver in Windows 7 Device manager?

Tags: graphics, drivers

I recently switched to Windows 7(x64) and all things work fine except my AMD Graphics card Driver(AMD Radeon R5 M330) is missing so I tried to install Drivers from the official site of AMD(They still support drivers for windows 7) but after the installation there is a problem in **Device manager** it says *"Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)"* and the Radeon Software won't even open saying the right driver is not installed on your PC but It was working fine in Windows 10 with the same(Win-10 version) latest Drivers so What can I do to fix this problem ?

Comment: What CPU do you have[?](https://superuser.com/questions/1156317/nvidia-graphics-card-no-longer-works-in-windows-10-error-code-43-but-works-in) I have a very specific reason for asking that question.

Comment: Intel Core I3-6006U

Comment: Do you have the Intel display drivers installed?

Comment: Yes all drivers are installed and up to date.

Comment: You should uninstall the Intel display drivers since you have an AMD GPU.

Comment: I tried uninstalling that and it doesn't work.........

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. I had exactly the same issue with a Sony VAIO VGN-CR353 laptop that has AMD Radeon Mobility x2300 GPU running Windows 7 x64. If you try to force an unsigned driver of the official AMD Catalyst driver or AMD WHQL or Microsoft Vista/W7 WHQL driver (i.e. boot with driver signing disabled) it will do it but after a reboot it will show Error 43. I spent *days* on this and finally solved it. The basic problem was caused by software developers who were lacking a few extra (and required) IQ points.
To fix it first uninstall all of the previous random drivers, especially any 'official' AMD drivers and/or other random Win7 x64 x2300 drivers you tried to install.
Go to the Microsoft Update Catalog and search for "ATI X2300"
e.g. https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=ATI+X2300
Download the file that is listed "ATI Technologies Inc. - Display - ATI Mobility Radeon X2300" for Windows 7 and dated 11/30/2008 with file size 20.3MB.
This is the only *true* Windows 7 x64 signed driver that is available.
You will end up with this file....
20232705_a9cff6669e7ea32aba78f5d4f87e9a8c5f253f02.cab
Exact file size is 21,258,168 bytes.
Double-click the file and it will open up. Select all files, right click and select 'extract'.
Save all the files to anywhere in a temp dir (let's say on the desktop in a dir called 'temp').
Now the trick part. This is where the developers screwed up. Make a new dir in the temp dir called "B_72960".
Now copy ALL the files you extracted into that directly as well (leave the temp dir files there).
Now go to control panel / device manager and right click on the Display Adapter (in my case it was Standard VGA Adapter put here using an automatic driver search in Windows Update) and select 'update driver software'.
Select 'browse my computer' and navigate to the temp dir where the driver files are. Just select the temp dir.
Click Next and it will find the driver for the ATI Radeon Mobility x2300 and install the driver. Reboot and Bob is very much your uncle.
The missing B_72960 directory is the key because the .inf file has that path hard-coded in the install script. Without that directory the signed ATI Radeon Mobility x2300 driver is found but it only gives an error saying a file could not be found and the developers obviously thought they didn't need to specify what file or where it should be looking for the file. It just hard quits.
So the x2300 driver install on Win 7 x64 problem is solved. Edit: p.s. Is there a way to format answers here with paragraphs and blank line separators? Wow what a mess, the whole answer is now one giant block of text.